# How to store each file in a zip archive, in an array using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-construction, zip, archive

Ideally, I want to just read the zip archive and store each of the files in an Iterable ready to be compiled. (assume the zip only contains .java files)

Something like this would be good, but this won't work as I can't get the path of each file in the zip.

```
private ArrayList<String> javaFilePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(javaFilePaths);
```

Is it possible to have each element of the `ArrayList` to be the path to a file in the archive? So far I've only been able to go through the zip archive and get all the filenames which is useless as when I call `getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(javaFilePaths);` it will not be the full path to the file. Maybe I need to store the content of each file in a new `JavaFileObject` first? Really not sure of the best way to go about this...

Can someone please help with this, it's proving very tricky!

`UPDATE:`

Thinking maybe of storing each file in the zip archive as a `File` object in an array of type `File`

Then calling the `getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(arrayOfFiles);` method.

Solutions, ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but have a look at `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`

Comment: @orid I "think" I need to iterate through the zip file and store each .java file as a `File` object in an array/list of type `File`

Comment: you should not "think" . you should know what you need and what you want to ask

Comment: You can't store `ZipEntry` as .java file as these will probably contain bytecode, unless you are sure it's a `JarInputStream` which contain some artifacts sources

Comment: @A.J Sorry, but I'm not a Java guru and I don't understand everything. That's why I came here where there's lots of experience. I know the general concept but I don't know how to go about it programmatically. The main concept is that a user browses for a zip archive containing Java files, the Java files are then stored temporarily in memory and then compiled producing the class files. I have everything working, apart from how to store the files from a zip folder into an array.

Comment: @orid So, I first need to perform some type of decompression for it to be stored as a valid .java file to be compiled?

Comment: you understood me wrong. I am not asking you to be Java Guru. I am asking you to know what you want to do. if you don't , we won't be able to help. :)

Comment: @A.J. Ok, well for this specific part of my program. There is a zip archive containing .java files which I store as type `File`. I need to make an `Iterable` object of those files as type `JavaFileObject`. My idea is to first make an array of `File` objects and then feed the array to the method `fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(arrayOfFiles);`

Comment: I am not sure that you can get a valid `File` from something *inside* a ZIP... Is there no possibility of unzipping it beforehand?

Comment: I think you probably need to settle for having an array of ZipInputStream or some such -- I don't think plain vanilla File can be made to point to a zip member.

Comment: (Of course, you could, in theory, subclass File to do what you want.)

Comment: @MichaelRose That's what I'm starting to think too... I don't really want to create an unzipped directory as I'll just have to delete it afterwards.

Comment: Added an answer, anyone have some ideas on improvement?

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented on your answer as you requested but comments are limited in length.
It is possible to achieve what you want: compiling the source without actually extracting it to a physical file on the file system.

quoting from the API of the interface [StandardJavaFileManager](http://exoa.postech.ac.kr:8080/java5/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html)

> This file manager creates file objects representing regular files, **zip file entries**, or entries in similar file system based containers

searching in google I found the following article: [Create dynamic applications with javax.tools](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/)

in the section "Java compilation: Concepts and implementation" it states the following on "source files":

> one or more .java source files to compile. JavaFileManager provides an abstract file system that maps source and output file names to JavaFileObject instances. (**Here, file means an association between a unique name and a sequence of bytes. The client doesn't need to use an actual file system**.)

The following article also does the same: [Dynamic in-memory compilation](http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/)

Both use CharSequence as the source to compile.
You can try to build your own implementation based on the explanation in the articles above with the change of being based on ZipEntry. otherwise, you can read the contents of the zip entry (as you mentioned, you know its a java source file) into a StringBuffer and just use the implementation from one of the articles to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You could scan the ZIP file and keep the references to its entries. Then select the entry from the list, extract the file and do whatever you need to do with it. It is not necessary to fully read all files initially. One drawback: You must not call `ZipFile.close()` until you are finished with processing the ZIP archive.

For example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class SO {
    static class ZipFileRecord {
        final ZipFile zf;
        final ZipEntry ze;

        public ZipFileRecord(ZipFile zf, ZipEntry ze) {
            super();
            this.zf = zf;
            this.ze = ze;
        }

        public String content() throws IOException {
            InputStream is = zf.getInputStream(ze);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            int count = 5;  // limit loop for reduced output
            while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                if (count--<=0) {
                    sb.append("...\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
    public static class ZipWalker {
        final ArrayList<ZipFileRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ZipFile zf;

        public void scan(String fn) throws ZipException, IOException {
            File f = new File(fn);
            if (!f.exists()) throw new RuntimeException("File not found: " + f);
            zf = new ZipFile(f);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zf.entries();
            for (ZipEntry ze : Collections.list(entries)) {
                if (ze.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
                    list.add(new ZipFileRecord(zf, ze));
                }
            }
        }

        public void dump() throws IOException {
            int count = 3;  // limit loop for reduced output
            for (ZipFileRecord fr : list) {
                System.out.println("=============> " + fr.ze);
                System.out.println(fr.content());
                if (count--<=0)
                    break;
            }
            zf.close();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ZipException, IOException {
        ZipWalker zw = new ZipWalker();
        zw.scan("path/to/your/file.zip");
        zw.dump();
    }
}
```

Noteworthy things:

1. The `scan` method does the scanning, the `dump` method represents all the other things, which you want to do with the files.
2. `ZipFile.close()` must be called after you are finished with the ZIP file. You can't read data from its entries, if `close()` has been called.
3. The `count` variables in the code are for output brevity - you need to remove those and the associated `if`s.
4. For simplicity I used `Reader` and `UTF-8`. If you present the file content to the user, you may have to deal with the file's charset. You may also have to deal with it for compilation.

Comment: Please see my answer and advise if you have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost there, it works however the FileOutputStream creates the file, I could simply delete it after, but is there a way to do this without the creation of the file, and instead let it be virtual? Comment on my answer please.

```
btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        isZip = true;
                        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
                        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
                            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();
                            File file = new File(zipEntry.getName());
                            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                            int length;
                            while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                                fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
                            }
                            is.close();
                            fos.close();
                            fileArrayList.add(file);
                        }
                        zipFile.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you need. Right now I am working on my main projects (the ones which pay my bills), but I will spend some of my "stackoverflow time" tomorrow on this topic. I thought, that this is primarily about "virtualizing the ZIP into an array". Probably you need more details on wiring it together with JavaCompiler and friends?

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I actually have it successfully compiling from a JTextArea, and now I'm adding the next feature which is to browse for a zip containing multiple Java source files to be compiled :) I'm enjoying this project a lot since it's challenging my knowledge (first year computer science student).